# Steps to develop 2.5D web mapping application

Tags: geoserver, web-mapping

I am developing a 2.5D GIS application. We are using GeoServer for layers.
We created building images which supports 2.5/3D
Already we have developed GIS application using OpenLayers, MapFish etc.

Please any body can guide me to develop this application?

Comment: what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: Hi iant,

To develop a 2.5d Virtual city (like www.youcity.com) application using Flash/Javascript API.

Answer (score 1):

[youcity.com](http://www.youcity.com/2009/website_front/index.html) looks like a "normal" tiled web map that uses a per-rendered "3d" city panorama. Additionally, there is a mouse-over effect. That shouldn't be too difficult either.